# Maximal solution and its domain of $x'(t) = x(t)^{x(t)}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

How can I proof that the maximal solution to

\begin{align}
x'(t) = x(t)^{x(t)}, \quad x(0) = x_0,
\end{align}

where $x_0 > 0$ and $t \geq 0$, is not (globally) defined on $\mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$?

I am given the hint that it might help to first look at $x_0 > 1$. Unfortunately, that does not help. I am close to giving up on this one so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a little more direct, we know that $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$ has a minimum of $e^{-e^{-1}}>0.6922>\frac12$ at $x=e^{-1}$. So we know that the solution is growing at least with the rate $\frac12$. So we can be sure that $x(t)\ge 2$ for $t\ge 4$, assuming the domain of the maximal solution $x$ extends far enough to contain $t=4$.

After that, $x'\ge x^2$ so that
$$
x(t)\ge\frac{x(4)}{1-x(4)(t-4)}
$$
forces a divergence to infinity shortly after that point (as $x(4)\ge 2$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can follow your argument up to $x' \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Unfortunately I do not understand the rest. Would you mind explaining it a bit more detailed?

Comment: So $x(t)\ge x_0+\frac12t$ which evaluates with $x_0>0$ to $x(4)>2$. Now if $x>2$, then $x^x>x^2$, next use separation of variables to solve the differential inequality.